# Choosing a folder updates all entry in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm8Tk.png)There are two buttons one will choose a file and one will choose a directory and will update respective entries in tkinter. But if anyone is chosen it updates other entries.
In the screenshot attached I just selected file by clicking the browse button but it updated both entries.
Below is the code. Please help.
Mainly trying to select a folder and select a excel file and verify if the sheet exists. So this part is working fine. Only problem is over updating the entries.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.filedir = tk.Entry(self, text=" ")
        self.filedir.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.load_button = tk.Button(self, text="Browse...", command=self.loadFile)
        self.load_button.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.projectdir = tk.Entry(self, text=" ")
        self.projectdir.grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.choose_dir = tk.Button(self, text="Select Folder", command=self.chooseDir)
        self.choose_dir.grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=4,columnspan=3)

    def chooseDir(self):
        dirName = askdirectory(title='Please select a directory')
        self.projectdir.delete(0, "end")
        self.projectdir.insert(0, dirName)

    def loadFile(self):
        filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("info", "*.xlsx"), ("all file", "*.*")))
        extension = filename[filename.rfind('.'):]
        if extension == '.ods':
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message")
        else:
            vVerify = self.verifyExcel(filename)
            if vVerify == 1:
                self.verify_button = tk.Button(self, text="Verified")
                self.verify_button.grid(row=1,column=2)
                self.filedir.delete(0, "end")
                self.filedir.insert(0, filename)
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message 1")




app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and share minimum code to reproduce issue.

Comment: @Kamal updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `text=" "` from your `entry` widgets to avoid creating a common textvariable `" "`.

```
    class StartPage(tk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            self.filedir = tk.Entry(self)
            self.projectdir = tk.Entry(self)
            ...
```

Comment: I need two entries and two buttons. Button1 will choose a path and update the entry with chosen directory and Button2 will choose a file and update the entry.
My problem is my code is working fine except choosing a directory updates both entries and choosing file also updates both entries.

Comment: That is because you put `text=" "` when you create your `filedir` and `projectdir` and it created a common textvariable `" "`. Just remove both and it will work fine.